# in-house records over outside records

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am stuck with this problem.
I have duplicates in my query coming from that some of the records are in-house and outside simultaneously. I prefer in-house over outside but some of the outside are preferable when there is no entrance from in-house.

Select id, date, location from prod

```
id date        location
----------
2  01/01/2012  in-house
2  05/01/2012  outside <- in this situation i want to keep just in-house

id date        location
----------
4  01/01/2012  in-house
5  03/01/2012  outside <- in this situation i want to keep both since there is no db entry for id=5 therefor i have just info from outside
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Can you edit your question, perhaps? I don't think it's clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Can I try to para-phrase?  You want one record returned per `id`?  And that should be chosen with `location = outside` having precedence over `location = in-house`.  And, I presume, if there are still multiple records for that `id`, choose the one with the highest `date` value?  *[Also, what brand of SQL are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?  And what release/version?]*

Comment: Hi, i have access to SQL Server. If there are multiple rec for id i would like max date value and always choosing in-house over outside. Sorry i am aware it isnt clearest explanation but you are grasping it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to do a full outer join from your table to itself and then use coalesce.

```
 Select 
    COALESCE(Inside.Id, outside.id) Id,
    COALESCE(Inside.date, outside.date) Date,
    COALESCE(Inside.location, outside.location) Location
From 
    prod Inside
    FULL OUTER JOIN prod Outside
    ON Inside.id = Outside.iD
    and Inside.location <> Outside.Location
Where
    (Inside.Location = 'in-house'
    or 
    Inside.Location is null)
    and 
    (outside.Location = 'outside'
     or
     outside.Location is null)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c743d/11)

Notes:

If your fields can be nullable you may want to use a Case statement instead of coalesce and use the ID field to determine which table to use. Using the date as an example

```
CASE WHEN Inside.Id is not null THEN Inside.date ELSE outside.date END date
```

As Dems noted this also assumes that `{id, location}` is unique.

**UPDATE**

Since you're using SQL Server and {ID, Location} isn't unique and you want the max date value and always choosing in-house over outside then you can use `ROW_NUMBER/WHERE RowNumber = 1` effectively here, by ordering First on location and then by date.

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER ( partition BY ID 
               ORDER BY CASE LOCATION WHEN  'in-house' THEN 0  
                                      WHEN  'outside' THEN 1 END, 
                        DATE DESC) rn, 
                ID, 
                Date, 
                Location 
         FROM   prod) 
SELECT ID, 
       Date, 
       Location 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c743d/16)

Note We didn't have to use a case statement but I wanted the mapping to be explicit.

Comment: Conrad Frix - thank you very much - applied it and it works - now i need to understand the logic but you were great. thx

Comment: @Gronzy glad to help. BTW if you add more test cases, remove the where clause and add rn to the Select clause it might make more sense. [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09d01/1)

Comment: @ConradFrix this is very neat - now i wish it could be as easy for me as you just produced it but maybe with a time. Anyway thanks again.